# How can I scroll window to element in AngularJS using anchorscroll()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a scrollTo effect in AngularJS on an ng-click event, [following the example in this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1khqFUxPSi16uBVsY16f?p=preview).

I'm trying to scroll to categoryhead, like so:

```
myApp.controller('FoodCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $anchorScroll) {

//other stuff 

$scope.loadFood = function(category) {
 //other stuff

  //Scroll category head to top of page
  $scope.categoryhead = "#" + category;
  $location.hash($scope.categoryhead);
  $anchorScroll();

 //Ajax load stuff
 };  
});
```

I have the value of $scope.categoryhead printing out in the template and can see that it is the correct ID for each element, but the window doesn't get scrolled. Am I doing something wrong in trying to pass the element ID to $anchorscroll()?

[Here's my Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/STtV1ORclknwriXZgMR4?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after a while. I was specifying `$scope.categoryhead` incorrectly.

[Here's a Plunkr with anchorscroll(); to various page elements.](http://plnkr.co/edit/NvAdFWay46A9naw7zG3X?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

you missed out the css to apply so as no height is given its not showing scroll

```
.scroll{
  height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

here is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uZRYk2LcmjlW3ttfNmL3?p=preview)

Comment: No, the original doesn't depend on a height & overflow setting on .scroll. It still works if you remove them.